# Не могу запустить Angular приложение на vps вместе с Java приложением

Tags: spring-boot, angular, vps

Я создал проект, он состоит из двух компонентов, бекенд на Java Spring Bootи фронтенд на Angular. Я запустил jar файл на vps и он работает, настроил nginx для него. Потом я собрал Angular для продакшена с помощью  "ng build --prod" и в папке dist создались файлы для публикации. В одном из туториалов было сказано, что нужно закинуть файлы из папки dist в папку var/www на vps и при установленном nginx сайт начнет работать. Но он не работает. Нужно ли на сервере его как-то запустить, как это делается в приложении "ng serve" или проблема в nginx. В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо!

Вот файл nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
 root /var/www/html;

 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name ip_моего_сервера;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
        }
```